# How do I debug Commerce Order Comments token not expanding in Message?

Tags: tokens, commerce

Using Kickstart 2 with Commerce Message.

The token [message:message-commerce-order:field_order_comments] has begun to -sometimes- not expand. ie. sometimes it render as expected, but sometimes not. And when it doesn't there isn't an error in the error_log.

I've read that with some tokens one changes the underscores to dashes. ie.

```
[message:message-commerce-order:field-order-comments]
```

...I tried that and again, sometimes it works and sometimes not.

I have run into this problem time and time again with certain tokens in that they simply don't appear in `hook_tokens()` when I think they should 'fire'.

In this case, I worked around it by using the exact same code in `hook_message_presave()` and it works fine.

```
$message->arguments['!order-comments'] = array(
    'callback' => 'commerce_message_order_comments',
    'pass message' => TRUE,
  );
```

So I know the token -should- work. I really want to understand the mechanism so I can use these in the future.

So... How do I troubleshoot this? What am I missing?